# Has "which were" been omitted before " noted" in this text?

Tags: grammar, sentence-patterns, grammatical-roles, writing-advice, style-manuals

Has "which were" been omitted before " noted" in this text?

> But there is no other evidence that the Persians of this period were the slaves of any such superstitions as that noted by Ammianus.

Comment: Yes or no. I'm not sure the sentence is 100% correct. I'd rewrite it as EITHER 1. "were the slaves of any such superstitions as noted by Ammianus" (= Ammianus noted they were no slaves to...) OR 2. "were the slaves of any such superstitions as those noted by Ammianus" (= were no slaves to the superstitions which were noted by Ammianus ). In the 1st case "was" between "as" and "noted" is omitted. In the the latter yes: "which were".

Comment: *Any such superstitions* is plural, is it not? So *that* should be *those.*

Comment: Or possibly _superstitions like the one noted_.

Comment: @Xanne Because the sentence is so poorly phrased, it's not clear to me if the pronoun is referring to *evidence* (singular *that*) or *superstitions* (plural *those*). For instance, assuming the interpretation that it poorly refers to *evidence*, it should be rephrased like this: *But there is no evidence [other than **that** noted by Ammianus] that the Persians of this period were the slaves of any such superstitions.*

Comment: In short, we have no idea exactly what the intended meaning of the sentence is. The syntax is so poor that it's ambiguous. (Additional context, such as the sentences both before and after,  would probably clear it up.)

Comment: Jason, could you be rather harsh there? Of course superstitions (plural those) but how could you really get evidence (singular that) without, for instance, changing "as…" to "than that"?